# How to handle file processing request in Django?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, celery, django-celery

I am making a Django Rest framework based server and in one of the request, I get an audio file from front-end, on which I need to run some ML based algorithm(I have script for same) and respond back to user with the result. Problem is that this request might take 5-10 seconds to execute. I am trying to understand following things:

1. Will Celery help me reduce the workload on server, as in any case I need to wait for the result of the ML Algo and respond back to user.
2. Should I create a different server to handle this type of request? Will that be a better approach?
3. Also, is my flow of doing things correct. First, Upload the file to some cloud platform for storage and serialize the instance to get the url of file. Second run the script using celery and wait for the result. Third, Respond back with the result.

Thanks for helping.

Comment: There are multiple ways to handle this. Main thing is you probably don't want the user to have to wait for the response that long (and occupy a connection socket waiting for your task to finish). So yes, celery could help to start a task in the background. You should return a response to the user as soon as you've saved the audio file ("Third" step shouldn't wait for script to end). Then on the front end you'll want to poll back regularly to check if the result is ready. Whether you should offload to a different server: only start doing that once you see your first server is getting too busy.

Comment: Also note that depending on where you host, you could also use server less functions of your hosting provider instead of celery, e.g. lambda by AWS.

Comment: Hi @dirkgroten. Suppose, I am fine with user waiting for the response. In fact that is the preferred way here. Basically, I want to give the response in one go. So, I think I will offload the work by celery and wait for the response before sending the reponse back to user? Will that help django server handle more requests. Basically, if I will use celery, will it improve server performance?

Comment: It really depends on what limits the performance. My first reaction is that it won't help, because let's say you spawn 10 gunicorn/uwsgi processes to handle 10 simultaneous requests (and you are memory limited, each process using 1/10th of the total available memory) then you are blocking 1 process until you return the response. But you may be CPU limited (if your ML script takes up a lot of CPU and you're not offloading to GPU) in which case offloading to a different machine would help. So this cannot be answered without actually looking at the data.